# python3 pdb in emacs setup

Tags: python-3.x, emacs, pdb

I am using emacs on ubuntu server, and it is of this version:

```
GNU Emacs 24.5.1
```

If I run pdb inside emacs to debug my python code, by default it is of python2, and it looks like this in emacs:
[image]

Where in the left window, I can specify my running command and in the right window, it has a "=>" pointing to exactly which line of file is being executed at this moment.

But what I am really looking for is the python3 environment in my emacs, and someone suggests me to add such setting in my .emacs file:

```
(setq gud-pdb-command-name "python3 -m pdb")
```

By adding such, it does invoke the python3 when pdb is invoked in my emacs. But I don't see 2 separate windows as previous. I only got one window.

Does anyone know how to make this 2-window mode happen? I could have separate the emacs into 2 windows by extra command, but the user experience is totally different.

Any suggestions.

Thanks,

Jack